# Why does grep -o add blank lines?

Tags: grep

I have a plain text file with single-character line-terminators, and I want the first word on each line.  I tried with 'grep -o' but it adds blank lines to the output:

```
bash-3.2$ file file
file: ASCII text
bash-3.2$ cat -ve file
aaaa bbbb cccc dddd$
eeee ffff gggg$
hh$
iiii jjjj kkkk$
ll$
mm nn$
bash-3.2$ grep -o '[^ ]*' file
aaaa

eeee

hh
iiii

ll
mm

bash-3.2$
```

I can't see where the extra blank lines are coming from.

It got more confusing when I tried to require at least one
character on each line:

```
bash-3.2$ grep -o '[^ ][^ ]*' file
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
eeee
ffff
gggg
hh
iiii
jjjj
kkkk
ll
mm
nn
bash-3.2$
```

Now it's splitting the lines into fields and printing all of them.

I eventually switched over to awk, but I'd really like to understand why the
-o flag to grep causes it to do this.

Comment: `[^ ]*` matches **zero or more** chars other than space, so it matches every string.

Comment: The pattern you are looking for is `"^\w+` which means match only letters that start at the begining of each line

Comment: I understand about it matching zero or more characters; what I don't understand is that the manual says grep prints out matching lines; it doesn't say anything about grep splitting a line into multiple separate lines and then matching them all separately.

Why does 'aaaa bbbb' become two lines, when it's just one line in the file?

Comment: Update: the manual on my Mac reads:

`     -o, --only-matching`
`             Prints only the matching part of the lines.`

But the manual on the Linux box reads:

`       -o, --only-matching`
`              Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line,`
`              with each such part on a separate output line.`

So it may be that the manual is out of date.